# delete a class with classList remove

Tags: javascript, list, class

I tried in different way classList remove to delete a class but nothing.
I also read a topic already posted here but it does not seem to be exactly the same.

Do you have an idea where I was wrong?

```
<div class="block_AddElement_Categories">
    {% for key, categorie in categories %}
          <input onchange="depliantCat('{{key}}');" value="{{key}}" id="{{key}}" name="categorie" type="radio">
          <label for="{{key}}">{{key}}</label>
            {% for children in categorie  if children is defined %}
                  <div class="reveal-if-active {{key}}">
                      <input class="catEnfantActive" id="{{children}}" value="{{children}}" name="categorie" type="radio">
                      <label class="catEnfantActive" for="{{children}}">{{children}}</label>
                  </div>
            {% endfor %}
   {% endfor %}
</div>
```

I have a radio list on two levels, and I try to add a class when the parent's click, which shows the child list.

The code works to make the child list appear but does not close it because it still does not delete the class I added.

```js
function depliantCat(nom) {

    sousCategorie = document.querySelectorAll('.' + nom);

    if (document.getElementById(nom).checked = true) {
        for(var i = 0; i < sousCategorie.length; i++) {
            sousCategorie[i].classList.add('catParentActiveChecked');
        }
    }

    else if (document.getElementById(nom).checked = false) {
        for(var i = 0; i < sousCategorie.length; i++) {
            sousCategorie[i].classList.remove('catParentActiveChecked');
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div class="foo">1</div>
<div class="foo">2</div>
<div class="foo">3</div>
<div class="bar">4</div>
<div class="bar">5</div>
<input type="checkbox" id="foo" onchange="depliantCat(this)" />Foo<br>
<input type="checkbox" id="bar" onchange="depliantCat(this)" />Bar
<style>
    .catParentActiveChecked {
        color:red;
    } 
</style>
<script>
    function depliantCat(el) {
            var nom = el.id;
            sousCategorie = document.querySelectorAll('.' + nom);
            if (el.checked) {
                for(var i = 0; i < sousCategorie.length; i++) {
                    sousCategorie[i].classList.add('catParentActiveChecked');
                }
             }
            else {
                for(var i = 0; i < sousCategorie.length; i++) {
                    sousCategorie[i].classList.remove('catParentActiveChecked');
                }
              }
         }
</script>
```

You can use *change* event and you need to replace **=** with **==** in your conditions or remove operator at all, if checked is boolean:

```
if( checked == true )
```

is the same as

```
if( checked )
```

and

```
if( checked == false )
```

is the same as

```
if( !checked )
```

See https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_operators.asp

**=** is assignment operator while **==** is comparison operator

I don't know how your code is organized but you could use shorter version:

```
function depliantCat(el) {
            sousCategorie = document.querySelectorAll('.' + el.id);
            for(var i = 0; i < sousCategorie.length; i++) {
                    sousCategorie[i].classList.toggle('catParentActiveChecked');
            }
         }
```

And with jQuery it would be something like this

```
<div class="foo">1</div>
<div class="foo">2</div>
<div class="foo">3</div>
<div class="bar">4</div>
<div class="bar">5</div>
<input type="checkbox" id="foo" class="souschanger" />Foo<br>
<input type="checkbox" id="bar" class="souschanger" />Bar

<style>
    .catParentActiveChecked {
        color:red;
    } 
</style>

<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>
    $(function(){
       $(".souschanger").change(function() {
           $("."+this.id).toggleClass('catParentActiveChecked');
       });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: so I updated my message because I did not think to specify that it is parental input, child type radio, double level.